# Woocommerce child theme - overriding woocommerce support in child theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, child-theming

I am using underscores as a parent theme. It declares Woocommerce support like this:

```
function _s_woocommerce_setup() {
add_theme_support(
    'woocommerce',
    array(
        'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
        'single_image_width'    => 300,
        'product_grid'          => array(
            'default_rows'    => 3,
            'min_rows'        => 1,
            'default_columns' => 4,
            'min_columns'     => 1,
            'max_columns'     => 6,
        ),
    )
);
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
```

}

How do I remove or override the settings in a child theme. For instance, I want the thumbnail width to be 300px for the child theme. How is this achieved?  Can I remove theme support and re-add it?

And to clarify I have unsucessfully tried this:

```
function remove_parent_settings(){
remove_theme_support( 'thumbnail_image_width' );
remove_theme_support( 'gallery_thumbnail_image_width' );
remove_theme_support( 'single_image_width' ); }
```

And then

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_settings', 99 );
```

Comment: What is the whole function?

Comment: @HowardE edited post and visible here: https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/inc/woocommerce.php

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in child theme.

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
  add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
  add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
  add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
  add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It does not work, It seems like a standard answer to someone who does not know how to add theme support.  That is not the question. The question is how to override the settings of theme support if it has already been added in the parent theme.